# GeoServer startup problem and Error 503

Tags: geoserver, windows

I've been trying to set up Windows GeoServer version 2.15.2 through the binary installation, and am getting the following error when trying to access the admin interface

```
    HTTP ERROR 503
Problem accessing /geoserver/. Reason:

    Service Unavailable
Powered by Jetty:// 9.4.12.v20180830
```

Something also seems to be going wrong during the startup which is different from similar questions on here: on line 13, it says something is "UNAVAILABLE", while for others it says "STARTING"

```
    Welcome to GeoServer!

JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_221

Please wait while loading GeoServer...

2019-08-23 20:06:31.567:INFO::main: Logging initialized @334ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog
2019-08-23 20:06:31.677:WARN:oejx.XmlConfiguration:main: Property 'jetty.port' is deprecated, use 'jetty.http.port' instead
2019-08-23 20:06:31.677:WARN:oejx.XmlConfiguration:main: Property 'http.timeout' is deprecated, use 'jetty.http.idleTimeout' instead
2019-08-23 20:06:31.677:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.4.12.v20180830; built: 2018-08-30T13:59:14.071Z; git: 27208684755d94a92186989f695db2d7b21ebc51; jvm 1.8.0_221-b11
2019-08-23 20:06:31.692:INFO:oejdp.ScanningAppProvider:main: Deployment monitor [file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/geoserver/webapps/] at interval 1
2019-08-23 20:06:32.331:INFO:oejw.StandardDescriptorProcessor:main: NO JSP Support for /geoserver, did not find org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet
2019-08-23 20:06:32.347:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:main: Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@1a5c39e{GeoServer,/geoserver,file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/geoserver/webapps/geoserver/,UNAVAILABLE}{C:\Program Files (x86)\geoserver\webapps\geoserver}
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.IterativeDescriptorProcessor.visit(IterativeDescriptorProcessor.java:84)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.IterativeDescriptorProcessor.process(IterativeDescriptorProcessor.java:71)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaData.resolve(MetaData.java:409)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1457)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:847)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:287)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:545)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:46)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:192)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:505)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:151)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:180)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.fileAdded(WebAppProvider.java:432)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:610)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:529)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:392)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:313)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:150)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:579)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:240)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:138)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:416)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:383)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1572)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1512)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1511)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:220)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:486)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:77)
Caused by:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/media/jai/util/ImagingListener
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler$Context.createInstance(ContextHandler.java:2655)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.StandardDescriptorProcessor.newListenerInstance(StandardDescriptorProcessor.java:1967)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.StandardDescriptorProcessor.visitListener(StandardDescriptorProcessor.java:1916)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.IterativeDescriptorProcessor.visit(IterativeDescriptorProcessor.java:84)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.IterativeDescriptorProcessor.process(IterativeDescriptorProcessor.java:71)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaData.resolve(MetaData.java:409)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1457)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:847)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:287)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:545)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:46)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:192)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:505)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:151)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:180)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.fileAdded(WebAppProvider.java:432)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:610)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:529)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:392)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:313)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:150)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:579)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:240)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:138)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:416)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:383)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1572)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1512)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1511)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:220)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:486)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:77)
Caused by:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.media.jai.util.ImagingListener
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:565)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler$Context.createInstance(ContextHandler.java:2655)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.StandardDescriptorProcessor.newListenerInstance(StandardDescriptorProcessor.java:1967)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.StandardDescriptorProcessor.visitListener(StandardDescriptorProcessor.java:1916)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.IterativeDescriptorProcessor.visit(IterativeDescriptorProcessor.java:84)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.IterativeDescriptorProcessor.process(IterativeDescriptorProcessor.java:71)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaData.resolve(MetaData.java:409)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1457)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:847)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:287)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:545)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:46)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:192)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:505)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:151)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:180)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.fileAdded(WebAppProvider.java:432)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:610)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:529)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:392)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:313)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:150)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:579)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:240)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:138)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:416)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:383)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1572)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1512)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1511)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:220)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:486)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:77)
2019-08-23 20:06:32.362:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@1bb07ed{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8585}
2019-08-23 20:06:32.362:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @1128ms
```

I'm using Java JRE 8, and running on port 8585.

Answer (score 2):

As it is not a windows setup you can't place the package under C:\Program Files because it gives an error for lack of permissions...

I had the same problem, I solved it moving the unzipped directory under 
C:\Geoserver 2.15.2\

I hope this solve your problem.

Comment: or run it as administrator

Answer (score -2):

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
```

Add this code to web.xml file, this resolved for me.